# PlayN Export runnable .jar File in Eclipse

Tags: playn

I'm unable to export a runnable .jar file.
When I export the java project (using the eclipse export wizard) and then try to run the resulting .jar file I only get errors that jwgl library can't be found!
What can I do to get a working .jar file?

Thanks in advance!
Regards Fleckdalm

Answer (score 0):

You can export runnable jar with maven. Just run

```
mvn package
```

and *projectname.jar* and *projectname-jar-with-dependencies.jar* will apear under *target* directory.